# Why the use of generator expression to link object library?

Tags: cmake

I understand the purpose of object libraries, but why does linking it to a target need to involve a generator expression?

```
add_library(myObjects OBJECT a.cpp b.cpp)
add_library(mainLib ${other_srcs} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:myObjects>) # Why not "PRIVATE myObjects" just like other files and targets?
```

From my understanding, generator expressions are useful for evaluating things available only during generation phase. Why would it be the case that object libraries, which are simply collection of object files, and their location not be known during the configuration phase?

Answer (score 0):

> Why would it be the case that object libraries, which are simply collection of object files, and their location not be known during the configuration phase?

Simple: the `target_sources` command may be used to add sources (and therefore objects) to a target at any point. If a variable were expanded immediately, one would miss objects that were added later.

In multi-config builds, it is also unknown at configuration time whether you refer to the *Debug* or *Release* objects.

---

Imagine that `add_library(target a.cpp b.cpp)` created a variable named `target_OBJECTS` containing `/path/to/a.o;/path/to/b.o`. Then the following sequence demonstrates the problem:

```
add_library(target a.cpp b.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp ${target_OBJECTS})       # (1)

# ... later ...
target_sources(target PRIVATE c.cpp)

# ... later ...
add_executable(utility util.cpp ${target_OBJECTS})    # (2)
```

Now how would (2) know about `/path/to/c.o`? You could have `target_sources` update that variable, but now a *single* object library has dependents that see different subsets of it. That's horribly confusing. Moreover, (1) wouldn't see `c.o`, which is maybe what's desired in *this* example, but that's not always true. Maybe your code is just organized to define custom commands to create generated sources later.

Making this imperative, rather than declarative like `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:target>`, imposes structure on CMake code akin to requiring targets in a Makefile to be topologically sorted. It also changes the meaning from "the object files for this target" to "the object files for this target *at this point in CMake execution time*", which is strictly more complicated to reason about while not offering any expressive advantage.

If you replace this code with the CMake 3.12+ object library linking support, it looks even more vexing:

```
add_library(target a.cpp b.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE target)            # (1)

# ... later ...
target_sources(target PRIVATE c.cpp)

# ... later ...
add_executable(utility util.cpp)
target_link_libraries(utility PRIVATE target)         # (2)
```

Now, looking at either call to `target_link_libraries(... target)`, one would reasonably expect the same objects to be added.

Comment: If the arguments for ```target_sources``` are object files specified during the configuration phase, they should be available then. Just like shared and static library targets, shouldn't they?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example further demonstrating the problem. It is _incorrect_ that object file paths are known at configuration time, anyway because of multi-config generators.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Alex Reinking has already said, the location of the object file may itself depend on the configuration, e.g. with the "Ninja Multi-Config" generator the object files of a target `t` are located in `<build-dir>/t/CMakeFiles/t.dir/<config>/<path-of-source-file-relative-to-dir-in-which-target-is-defined>/<src-file-name>.o`

So you're exactly in the situation that you only know the location at generation time, hence the need for a generator expression.

Comment: I wonder why doesn't the same thing apply to non-object libraries build in middle of the pipeline.

Comment: @User10482 What exactly do you mean? For non-object libraries, the final location is also only resolved at generation time, exactly for the same reason - it might be configuration dependent. So non-object libraries do behave exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, but they don't need generator expression like ```OBJECT``` library does. I can link them through ```target_link_libraries```.

Comment: @User10482 As @KamilCuk explained in their reply you can use `target_link_libraries` with `OBJECT` libraries since 3.12. However, for technical reasons you still sometimes need the `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:tgt>` generator expression. If you have an `OBJECT` library `o_base` and two object libraries `o1` and `o2` that both link against `o_base` (doesn't matter whether they link `PRIVATE`ly or `PUBLIC`ly) and an executable that links against both `o1` and `o2` you'll need to manually add `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:o_base>` to the executable still.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. So, it boils down to design decision made by the CMake developers, seeing they were able to remove this generator expression in the case @KamilCuk gave.

Comment: @User10482 Yes exactly. If the target objects were inherited like other properties then you'd end up linking against the objects of `o_base` twice, once for each library to which the object files have been propagated. This would then cause a linker error due to duplicate symbol definitions. Since deduplication of object-files would need special handling that other properties do not need (and also could be quite expensive) CMake doesn't transitively inherit the object files, but of course this could be changed if the developers wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

> add_library(mainLib ${other_srcs} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:myObjects>) # Why not "myObjects" just like other files and targets?

So:

```
  add_library(mainLib ${other_srcs} myObjects)
```

Because that would try to find a **file named** `myObjects` and compile it. The file has no extensions, so cmake will exit because the file does not exists and he doesn't know how to compile it anyway.

If you meant:

```
  add_library(mainLib ${other_srcs})
  target_link_libraries(mainLib PUBLIC myObjects)
```

The `link_libraries` dependency on object libraries did **not** work in older cmake when `OBJECT` libraries were introduced.

[The documentation on object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) explicitly mentions the form `add_library(... $<TARGET_OBJECTS:...)` and notes that since cmkae 3.12 `target_link_libraries` may be used with object libraries.

Comment: Linking an object library with `target_link_libraries` does not always remove the need for the `$<TARGET_OJBECTS:tgt>` generator expression, though. If you have a target `A` that links to an object library `Obj1`, which itself links to an object library `Obj2` you will need to use `target_sources(A PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Obj2>)` in addition to `target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE Obj1)` because objects aren't inherited transitively.

Comment: Ah, yes that's what I meant. Edited. So, the developers decided to roll with generator expression because ```link_libraries``` did not work during the initial time period?

Comment: `the developers decided to roll` ask them. `because link_libraries did not work during the initial time period?` cmake 3.11 did not support `taget_link_libraries` with object libraries. But that's just convenience, still using `add_library( $<TARGET_OBJECTS` would be _the_ preferred way.